# Need help on a sine curve equation where crest increases in each iteration but trough stays the same

Tags: c++, math, equation

As stated in Title, I need help with an equation of a sine curve where the top (crest) can increase in each iteration, but bottom (trough) stay the same.

The general equation for a sine curve is

```
y = a sin (bx+c)
```

But in this equation, it is taken as a given that the crest and the trough would stay the same throughout each 'loop'.

Currently, I know that if I change a, the crest and the trough would both change respectively.

What I want to know is if there is an equation that suits the condition outlined, or do I have to use if else statements in my program in order to 'cut' the trough?

I would prefer a mathematical solution, but any is fine.

What I'm using this for is to simulate a haze PSI over a period of time, with the haze increasing for each day, in a patterned way.

Edit: Added graph for visual representation.
Here is something like what I want. The difference is that the graph should go the other way (from small to big), and the trough stay the same.
http://www.fda.gov/ucm/groups/fdagov-public/documents/image/ucm109222.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you searching for something like this:

```
-1 + x + x Sin[x]
```

[Wolfram-Alpha Plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B-1%20%2B%20x%20%2B%20x%20Sin%5Bx%5D%2C%20%7Bx%2C%200%2C50%7D%5D)